# Images not showing over the local network in WordPress

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I have created a wordpress website on my local computer. I am able to access it over the local network by following the suggested answer on this question [Apache: Wordpress over local network](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30021265/apache-wordpress-over-local-network), Everything works, css and themes work properly, the only problem is the images are not appearing. Can someone assist me as to why it is happening?

Comment: Debug url of image in your browser

Comment: have you checked your image path? try opening images in new tab and see if it loads